# When I saved the map object with Sharedprefences, there was a Gson exception, and I didn't know how to modify the code

Tags: android, gson

When I saved the map object with Sharedprefences, there was a Gson exception, and I didn't know how to modify the code.

```
 public void setDayActData(Context context, int actId) {

            ActEntity mActEntityGet = new ActEntity();
            Map<Integer, ActEntity> mDayDataMap = new HashMap<Integer, ActEntity>();


            String jsonStrGet = SharedPreferencesHelper.getString(context, currentDate, "");


            if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(jsonStrGet)) {
                int actOfNum = 0;

                Gson gsonGet = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
                mDayDataMap = gsonGet.fromJson(jsonStrGet, new TypeToken<HashMap<Integer, ActEntity>>() {
                }.getType());
                mActEntityGet = mDayDataMap.get(actId);


                actOfNum = mActEntityGet.getActOfNum() + 1;


                ActEntity mActEntitySet = new ActEntity(actId, actOfNum);
                mDayDataMap.put(actId, mActEntitySet);

                Gson gsonSet =  new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
                String jsonStr = gsonSet.toJson(mDayDataMap);
                SharedPreferencesHelper.putString(context, currentDate, jsonStr);
            } else {

                ActEntity mActEntitySet = new ActEntity(actId, 1);
                mDayDataMap.put(actId, mActEntitySet);

                Gson gsonSet = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization().create();
                String jsonStr = gsonSet.toJson(mDayDataMap);
                SharedPreferencesHelper.putString(context, currentDate, jsonStr);
            }
        }
```

Stacktrace is:

```
Process: com.linkfit.heart, PID: 9363
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.linkfit.heart/com.linkfit.heart.activity.common.NewFrameAct}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3296)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3327)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:180)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5795)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:768)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:899)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
 at com.linkfit.heart.util.UserActivityUtils.setDayActData(UserActivityUtils.java:91)
 at com.linkfit.heart.fragment.main.HomeFragment.refreshData(HomeFragment.java:453)
 at com.linkfit.heart.fragment.main.HomeFragment.onResume(HomeFragment.java:256)
 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2120)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1147)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2153)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:522)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:511)
 at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6441)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3281)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3327) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:180) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5795) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:768) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
 at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
 at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:1)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852) 
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801) 
 at com.linkfit.heart.util.UserActivityUtils.setDayActData(UserActivityUtils.java:91) 
 at com.linkfit.heart.fragment.main.HomeFragment.refreshData(HomeFragment.java:453) 
 at com.linkfit.heart.fragment.main.HomeFragment.onResume(HomeFragment.java:256) 
 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2120) 
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1147) 
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286) 
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268) 
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2153) 
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223) 
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:522) 
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:511) 
 at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6441) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3281) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3327) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:180) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5795) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:768)
```

Comment: Please provide a longer log of the error

Comment: Please provide also the content of jsonStrGet

Comment: Thanks,I solved my problem.